# SWIFT: Push segue is resulting in a modal segue instead

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

In my storyboard, a modal segue takes the user to the Sign In screen (from the main screen). Then, I added a PUSH segue from the Sign Up screen to the next screen (Create Profile), which is embedded in a Navigation Controller (The Create Profile screen is the one with the "test" button included).

[image]

[image]

The segue to the Sign Up screen works fine. However, when a user enters their credentials and clicks "Sign Up", it does take them to the correct screen, but using a modal segue vs. a push segue. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is my Sign Up View Controller code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SignInViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBAction func signInButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(usernameField.text!, password:passwordField.text!) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if user != nil {

            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginUser", sender: self)

            self.usernameField.text = ""
            self.passwordField.text = ""

        } else {

            if let errorString = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                self.displayAlert("Login Failed", message: errorString)

            }

        }
    }

}

@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if usernameField.text == "" || passwordField.text == "" {

        self.displayAlert("Missing Field(s)", message: "Username and password are required")

    } else {

        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = usernameField.text
        user.password = passwordField.text

        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (succeded, error) -> Void in

            if let error = error {
                if let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    self.displayAlert("Sign Up Failed", message: errorString)

                }


            } else {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SignUpToCreate", sender: self)

                self.usernameField.text = ""
                self.passwordField.text = ""

            }
        }
    }
}

//Dismiss the sign in screen
@IBAction func closeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Format the text fields
    textFieldUI()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}








//Display alert function
func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//Textfield UI
func textFieldUI() {

    passwordField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 0))
    passwordField.leftViewMode = .Always
    usernameField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 0))
    usernameField.leftViewMode = .Always

}

}
```

Comment: where is ur performSegueWithIdentifier method ?

Comment: your sign in VC should have a navigation controller to make a push segue
!!

Comment: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SignUpToCreate", sender: self) is in the SignUpButton action.

Comment: that is a line of code, not a method!!!! it doesn't matter if you have it or remove it, if you are not implementing the perforSegue method!!!

Comment: @Mr.T I'm only implementing sign up at this point, and I'm wondering why the segue is modal vs. push when I've clearly selected it as a 'push' in my storyboard.

Comment: though u select it as push, it will be not pushed unless the VC has navigation controller in the storyboard!!!!

Comment: the VC which is pushing should have navigation controller

Comment: @Mr.T Ok, I see. So you're saying that I cannot present the Sign Up screen modally and then the Create Profile screen as a PUSH.  I have to embed the Sign Up screen in a Nav Controller?

Comment: yes!!!try that and see if it works or not, else update ur question with what u tried

Comment: make sure you get rid of the navigation controller between sign up and create profile screen.  Only sign up should be imbedded in nav con.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible:

```
Root --(modal)--> SignUp --(push)--> NavigationController<->Detail
```

The structure should be like this

```
Root --(modal)--> NavigationController<->Signup --(push)--> Detail
```

I think you got to the wrong design because you did not want to show the navigation bar in the sign up controller. You can prevent that by setting the view controllers `navigationBarHidden` before showing it.

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly what i was looking for